# Javascript Tree Class

Tags: javascript, tree, reinventing-the-wheel, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

I got caught in the trap of implementing my own data structure. I've created a very general tree structure, where each node gets one parent, some children, and holds a value.

I'm mostly looking for advice on how to make this code more idiomatic, but also functionality that might be missing from this class, or that isn't necessary. I would also like thoughts on how idiomatic the traverse function is, and if there's a better way to implement it.

```
function Node(value = 0, children = []) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = children;
    this.parent = undefined;
}

Node.from = function(node) {
    let that = Object.assign(new Node(), node);
    that.parent = undefined;
    that.children = node.children.map(n => (Node.from(n), n.parent = that));
    return that;
};

Node.prototype.add = function(...children) {
    for (child of children) {
        child.parent = this;
        this.children.push(child);
    }
};

Node.Traversal = {
    BreadthFirst: 1,
    DepthFirst: 2
};

Node.prototype.traverse = function(callback, mode = Node.Traversal.BreadthFirst) {
    if (mode == Node.Traversal.BreadthFirst) {
        let nodes = [this];
        while (nodes.length > 0) {
            const current = nodes.shift();
            callback(current);
            nodes = nodes.concat(current.children);
        }
    } else if (mode == Node.Traversal.DepthFirst) {
        callback(this);
        this.children.forEach(n => n.traverse(callback, false));
    }
    return this;
};

Node.prototype.reduce = function(callback, initial, mode) {
    let acc = initial;
    this.traverse(n => acc = callback(acc, n), mode);
    return acc;
};

Node.prototype.every = function(callback) {
    return this.reduce((a, n) => a && callback(n), true);
};

Node.prototype.some = function(callback) {
    return this.reduce((a, n) => a || callback(n), false);
};

Node.prototype.find = function(callback, mode) {
    return this.reduce((a, n) => a || (callback(n)? n: false), false, mode);
};

Node.prototype.includes = function(value) {
    return this.some(n => n.value === value);
};
```

Comment: Hello, could you maybe explain in more detail what your tree structure is, because there are many of them. This would help having a better review.

Comment: The goal is to provide an extremely general tree. Each node should have one parent, some number of children, and hold a value.

Comment: Alright that's a pretty good explanation, you should add it to your post. There's a close vote on your question, I suspect this is the reason. I wouldn't worry if I were you, in the event your question was to get closed, I'm sure it would be reopened, it's a good question.

Comment: How can I know if my question has a close vote?

Comment: Where can I see the close votes? Shouldn't the question author be able to see close votes on their question, even if they have low rep?

Comment: here's a post about it: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8744/wouldnt-it-be-more-useful-to-notify-ops-automatically-about-close-votes-instea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is overall well-thought-out, well-organized, and well-written.

There's at least one bug, and one oversight that I would consider a bug:

- In `traverse` your recursive call is passing the wrong second parameter:

  ```
  } else if (mode == Node.Traversal.DepthFirst) {
      callback(this);
      this.children.forEach(n => n.traverse(callback, false));
  }
  ```

  should read

  ```
  } else if (mode == Node.Traversal.DepthFirst) {
      callback(this);
      this.children.forEach(n => n.traverse(callback, Node.Traversal.DepthFirst));
  }
  ```
- in `add` you don't declare `child`.  Presumably is should read `for (let child of children)`

As to design decisions, there are several things you might want to consider.

- `add` might be improved with `return this`.
- I think a `clone` method might be a more common choice here than a static `from` function.
- You might find the ES6 `class` syntax slightly more explicit.  I wasn't a big fan of it when it was proposed, and I'm still not; I don't like the implication it suggests that JS OOP is particularly similar to Java/C# style OOP.  But it does carry a bit less cruft than the constant repetition of `Node.prototype`.
- Rather than use an enumeration of traversal types, you might want to consider simply using functions instead.  That is,

  ```
  Node.Traversal = {
      BreadthFirst: function(callback) {
          let nodes = [this];
          while (nodes.length > 0) {
              const current = nodes.shift();
              callback(current);
              nodes = nodes.concat(current.children);
          }      
      },
      DepthFirst: function(callback) {
          callback(this);
          this.children.forEach(n => n.traverse(callback,  Node.Traversal.DepthFirst));
      }
  };

  Node.prototype.traverse = function(callback, traversal = Node.Traversal.BreadthFirst) 
  {
      traversal.call(this, callback);
      return this;
  };
  ```

  This would make it easier for you to add another traversal, since you only have to do it in one place, and it lets users supply their own instead.
- Perhaps most importantly, you might want to drop the `parent` property.  You do not use it anywhere except in building or cloning a tree, and it can lead to real problems.  For instance, if you cloned a tree with `from` (and therefore ended up with non-empty parent nodes), you will not be able to call `JSON.stringify` on it due to the cyclic nature.

Putting this all together, here's an alternate version:

```js
console.clear() 

class Node {
  constructor (value = 0, children = []) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = children;
  }
  
  static Traversal = {
    BreadthFirst: function(callback) {
        let nodes = [this];
        while (nodes.length > 0) {
            const current = nodes.shift();
            callback(current);
            nodes = nodes.concat(current.children);
        }      
    },
    DepthFirst: function(callback) {
        callback(this);
        this.children.forEach(n => n.traverse(callback,  Node.Traversal.DepthFirst));
    }
  }
  
  clone () {
    let that = Object.assign(new Node(), this);
    that.children = this.children.map(n => n.clone());
    return that;
  }
  
  add (...children) {
    for (let child of children) {
      this.children.push(child);
    }
    return this;
  }

  traverse (callback, traversal = Node.Traversal.BreadthFirst) {
    traversal.call(this, callback);
    return this;
  }

  reduce (callback, initial, mode) {
    let acc = initial;
    this.traverse(n => acc = callback(acc, n), mode);
    return acc;
  }

  every (callback) {
    return this.reduce((a, n) => a && callback(n), true);
  }

  some (callback) {
    return this.reduce((a, n) => a || callback(n), false);
  }

  find (callback, mode) {
    return this.reduce((a, n) => a || (callback(n)? n: false), false, mode);
  }

  includes (value) {
    return this.some(n => n.value === value);
  }  
}

const tree = new Node ('A', [
  new Node('  B', [
    new Node('    D'),
    new Node('    E', [
      new Node('      G'),
    ]),
    new Node('    F')
  ]),
  new Node('  C') 
])

tree.children[0].children[2].add(new Node('      H')).add(new Node('      I'))

const log = ({value}) => console.log(value)
console.log('===============================')
console.log('Breadth-first')
console.log('===============================')
tree.traverse(log)
console.log('===============================')
console.log('Depth-first')
console.log('===============================')
tree.traverse(log, Node.Traversal.DepthFirst)
console.log('===============================')
console.log('Clone, Breadth-first')
console.log('===============================')
tree.clone().traverse(log)
console.log('===============================')
console.log('Clone, Depth-first')
console.log('===============================')
tree.clone().traverse(log, Node.Traversal.DepthFirst)
```

Comment: Is there a way to move `Node.traversal` inside the class block? It feels weird and too separate from the rest of the functions right now.

Comment: I agree that it's odd.  It's one of the many reasons that I don't like the current `class` syntax.  There is now a widely supported static *method* syntax, but nothing for other properties.  I've never really tried to learn why.

Comment: +1 For the class version

Comment: @AlexF There is now, you can use static for properties `static Traversal = {
    BreadthFirst(callback) {... }`

Comment: @Tofandel: Good to know.  Updated

Comment: @ScottSauyet Forgot to remove the old one ;) A suggestion on the add method as well `if (child instanceof Node) {
        this.children.push(child);
      } else {
        this.children.push(new Node(child));
      }`
and in the constructor `this.add(...children);` (you will need to initialize the children property in the class) `children = [];`
So you don't have to write `new Node` every time when writing a tree

Comment: @Tofandel: I removed the redundant code.  The other suggestion is less likely to me.  I'd suggest that you add another answer with that if you find it important.  Feel free to start from this code if you want.  I'm much more of a FP person than an OOP one, but if I do OOP, I prefer consistent interfaces -- either always use `new` or never use it.  If I were to write this for myself and not a code review, I would use just functions, no classes, no `new`s anywhere.  But that's not what this answer is for.

Answer (score 2):

#### Review

- Your code is compact and well organised. Reusing `traverse` and `reduce` allows for easy extensibility.
- Your `tree` could be a graph, or even worse a cyclic one: `traverse` could iterate to infinity.
- By adding additional methods such as `descendants` and `ancestors` you could guard that the structure remains a tree. When adding a node, it cannot have a parent, it cannot be the node self, it cannot be a descendant or an ancestor.
- You're allowing BFS and DFS, but only in *pre-order*. I would also include *post-order* (and perhaps also *in-order*).
- Adding additional properties in a node might be useful for certain use cases: `root`, `depth`, `height`, `isleaf`, `isbranch`

Comment: inorder traversal makes sense only for a binary tree.

Comment: @ScottSauyet For me, the pre- and post-order are the most important ones. The in-order probably doesn't have that many applications here. I would agree with you.

Comment: I do use `inorder` reasonably often, but it simply makes no sense when you don't have specific `left` and `right` children.

Comment: If I am going to add postorder traversal, would it make sense to split `traverse` into two different functions (one for breadth-first and one for depth-first)?

Comment: Yes with an optional parameter _order_; see the other answer how the split could be done.

Comment: But I wouldn't split all other methods into different search strategy and order. Does it really matter how you search for items (maybe it does)? But when executing actions when walking the tree, strategy and order definately must be available parameters/split methods.

Comment: @dfhwze: Agreed, I wouldn't bother unless there is some real reason to search or whatever in the order of a different traversal.  That would also require updating the traversals to allow for early escapes.  It's not worth it without a powerful reason.

Comment: @dfhwze It can matter when searching for items, because `find` only returns the first element that it matches (in order to act like `find` for arrays).

Comment: Ah good call didn't think about that one