# Javascript Tree Class 2

Tags: javascript, tree, reinventing-the-wheel, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

This question is the second version of the code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226709/javascript-tree-class).

I'm writing a general tree class. Specifically, each node should have oen parent, some number of children, and hold a value.

I'm looking for general advice on how to make this code more idiomatic. I'm also looking for thoughts on the `traverse` function, any functions that should be present in a general tree class but aren't, and also any way to simplify the existing functions.

```js
// Code to review
class Node {
 constructor(value = 0, children = []) {
  this.value = value;
  this.children = children;
 }

 traverse({ preorder, postorder, levelorder }) {
  if (levelorder) {
   let nodes = [this];
   while (nodes.length > 0) {
    const current = nodes.shift();
    levelorder(current);
    nodes = nodes.concat(current.children);
   }
  }
  else {
   if (preorder) preorder(this);
   this.children.forEach(n => n.traverse({ preorder, postorder }));
   if (postorder) postorder(this);
  }
  return this;
 }

 clone() {
  const copy = n => Object.assign(new Node(), n);
  let that = copy(this);
  that.traverse({ preorder: n => n.children = n.children.map(copy) });
  return that;
 }

 map(callback) {
  let that = this.clone();
  that.traverse({ levelorder: n => n.value = callback(n.value) });
  return that;
 }

 reduce(callback, initial) {
  let a = initial;
  this.traverse({ levelorder: n => a = (n === this && initial === undefined)? n.value: callback(a, n.value) });
  return a;
 }

 filter(callback) {
  let that = this.clone();
  that.traverse({ levelorder: n => n.children = n.children.filter(m => callback(m.value)) });
  return that;
 }

 every(callback) {
  return Boolean(this.reduce((a, b) => a && callback(b), true));
 }

 some(callback) {
  return Boolean(this.reduce((a, b) => a || callback(b), false));
 }

 find(callback) {
  return this.reduce((a, b) => (callback(b)? a.push(b): null, a), []);
 }

 includes(value) {
  return this.some(a => a === value);
 }
}

// Testing code
let tree = new Node(0);
let a = new Node(1);
let b = new Node(2);
let c = new Node(3);
let d = new Node(4);
let e = new Node(5);
let f = new Node(6);
tree.children = [a, b, c];
a.children = [d];
d.children = [e, f];

console.log("\nmap", tree.map(a => a + "2"));
console.log("\nreduce", tree.reduce((a, b) => String(a) + String(b)));
console.log("\nfilter", tree.filter(a => a < 3));

console.log("\nevery", tree.every(a => a < 3));
console.log("\nsome", tree.some(a => a < 3))

console.log("\nfind", tree.find(a => a > 2));
console.log("\nincludes", tree.includes(3));
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Review

Well written API, but I am not happy with this one:

> ```
> traverse({ preorder, postorder, levelorder })
> ```

`preorder` and `postorder` can be combined, but they are always mutually exclusive with `levelorder`.

> ```
> traverse({ preorder, postorder, levelorder }) {
>   if (levelorder) {
>       // levelorder ..
>   }
>   else {
>       // preorder conditional and/or postorder conditional ..
>   }
>   return this;
> }
> ```

Instead, use 2 separate methods, each doing their own well known type of traversal.

[DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

```
 traverseDepthFirst({ preorder, postorder })
```

[BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

```
 traverseBreadthFirst({ levelorder })
```

Some general thoughts:

- should you allow cyclic graphs?
- should you want to traverse up the ancestors?